# Converting first derivative into degrees

Tags: matlab

I have a very basic question. I am analyzing a movie. In the movie I am fitting a curve to define an object and computing the first derivative of a curve at it's starting point. The first derivative is changing in each frame. I want to measire the first derivative in the from of angle given in degrees or radians. Is there a faster way to do it in MATLAB.

I know its a very simple question, but if someone can explain me the concept then that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: What is this curve you're defining? How is the curve calculated? Please include some code to exemplify.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the curve is defined as `dy/dx` the ratio between the change in X direction and Y direction. This ratio is also the `tan` of the angle between the curve and the X axis. Therefore, if you want the angle (in radians) all you need it compute `atan` of the derivative.